# Google Search Console Mobile Test Passes But Then Fails Validation

Tags: html, css, google-search, google-search-console

I'm currently experiencing strange behaviour from the Google Search Console using Mobile Usability Testing. The page is showing as not mobile friendly due to clickable elements being too close together. All clickable elements on the page however have a margin of at least 10px (greater than Google's 8px guideline).

**Google Seach Console Report:**

[image]

If I however then click "Test Live URL" my website passes the Mobile Usability Test.

**Live Test:**

[image]

The crawled version and live version of the site are identical so this isn't a caching issue or that it hasn't been crawled for a while. I have no idea why it's passing the live validation but no the crawler validation, any ideas?

[Live Site](https://mattdavis.info/) if you would like to view the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting the same, with the addition of the "Content wider than screen" issue, which shouldn't be the case as there are carousel type horizontal scrolling elements which don't actually affect the page layout.

I've put it down to intermittent errors on Google's behalf, after testing various 'fixes' none of which worked. Been revisting SC every week or two and some pages throwing those errors have been automatically verified, but other new ones added, so doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced this strange behaviour for the first time. Exactly the same findings as OP but my validation failures are:

> Text too small to read
>
> Clickable elements too close together
>
> Content wider than screen

I have 3 pages failing and 3 others using the same template that pass. The only difference is text and image content. Even Lighthouse is happy. I've spent a few hours manually picking over the template in the browser, but I can't find a single issue. All font is 18px+, there are no overflows at any width etc.

It makes no sense! I'll keep an eye on them and see if the bots cheer up.